# How to check if two button in a list have the same opacity?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an issue with my application. I'm creating a "simple" mobile game where I have a list of a button that have an opacity of 0.4 and I take one random button in the list and set it opacity to 1. And my point is to have two button generated, so for now I just called the function twice at the start but the problem is that when the two button are the same it generates just one after. I hope you'll understand (I'm French).

```
'''        void ChooseFirstRandomButton()
    {
        var rand = new Random();

        var buttonList = new List<Button> { 
            one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine,
            ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen,
            sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty,
            twentyone, twentytwo, twentythree, twentyfour
        };

        int index = rand.Next(buttonList.Count);
        var randomButton = buttonList[index];
        var randomButtonOpacity = randomButton.Opacity;
        randomButton.Opacity = 1;
    }
'''
```

The "one", "two", ... are the name of my buttons.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Ok here you are, but there is no error it's just that when two button are generated and are the same it generate juste one after.

Comment: Make a variable `int iSpecial = index;` to store index of button you will set to your "special" opacity. Then when you want to change which button has that "special" opacity, you can write logic to do whatever you need: You can "restore" -- `buttonList[iSpecial] = OriginalOpacity;` Or you can ensure that you are changing to a different one -- `if (index == iSpecial) index = (iSpecial + 1) % buttonList.Count;`

Comment: Just tried what you said but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: As always, the best way to get help, is to add to question exactly what code you tried. Then say what you expected to happen (I'm not sure I understand your goal yet), and what happened instead. The next step is for *you* to debug what went wrong. Either with Visual Studio breakpoints, or Debug.WriteLine statements, to find out what values are not what you expect. Isolate the problem down to one or two places in code that don't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but someone foud a better way for me so I don't have problem anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a loop to continue picking numbers until you get one that hasn't already been chosen

```
// initialize your list of buttons and random seed 
// before the loop

bool loop = true;

while (loop)
{
    int index = rand.Next(buttonList.Count);
    var randomButton = buttonList[index];

    // if it's not set, set it and exit loop
    if (randomButton.Opacity != 1) 
    {
       randomButton.Opacity = 1;
       loop = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As from video you provided and your description "buttons meet each other" you just need to improve your algorithm:

1. create somewhere outside of the function a global variable:

```
    int opacity_1_index = -1;
```

2. after choosing random index, check if it is not equal to the one remembered:

```
    int index = rand.Next(buttonList.Count);
    if (index == opacity_1_index)
    {
            // exit function and call it again
    }
```

3. else remember this index and do the rest:

```
    else
    {
            opacity_1_index = index; // add this line
            var randomButton = buttonList[index];
            var randomButtonOpacity = randomButton.Opacity;
            randomButton.Opacity = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think it can work because "index" is not an opacity but a button and I didn't understand why you said "opacity_1_index = -1"

Comment: I called this variable "opacity_1_index" because it stores "index of a button with opacity = 1". You could also call this variable "previous_index".

Comment: And -1 is just a default value for this variable. You could also do "int opacity_1_index = 999;"

Comment: Ho okay I didn't know that